# SAS Java Pooling with Spring

Tags: java, spring, connection, sas, connection-pooling

I would like to setup C3P0 or Apache Connection Pooling in Java with Spring Framework that connects to SAS IOM Servers with [information read from SAS Metadata Sever](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/itechjcdg/61499/HTML/default/viewer.htm#connfact_omr.htm).

I have tried looking into the sample code and all of it uses `getConnection()` method on ConnectionFactory which returns a single MVA Connection. My question is, how do I setup Datasources with Connection Pooling using a Single Connection that's returned from a Connection Factory? Alternatively any pointers to SAS documentation/sample code w.r.t Spring Framework with SAS is greatly appreciated.

Here is the Sample Code that was provided in SAS Documentation:

```
     String classID = Server.CLSID_SASOMI;
     String host = "metadata.abc.com";
     int port = "1234";
     String userName = "admin";
     String password = "admin1";
     Server metadataServer = new BridgeServer(classID,host,port);
     ConnectionFactoryConfiguration metadataConfig = new ManualConnectionFactoryConfiguration(metadataServer);
     ConnectionFactoryInterface cxf = ConnectionFactoryManager.getConnectionFactory(metadataConfig);
     ConnectionInterface cx = cxf.getConnection(userName,password);
     org.omg.CORBA.Object obj = cx.getObject();
     IOMI iOMI = IOMIHelper.narrow(obj);
     String repositoryID = "A0000001.A1234567";
     String logicalServerName = "myServer";
     ConnectionFactoryConfiguration cxfConfig = new OMRConnectionFactoryConfiguration(iOMI,repositoryID,logicalServerName);
```

Comment: What makes you think you can use a `javax.sql.DataSource`  for this? This isn't JDBC code so imho a `DataSource` will not work here.

Comment: The reason why I think a Datasource would be viable for this is getConnection() method below returns an MVAConnection which is of type java.sql.Connection (which I was able to wrap into a Spring's Single Connection DataSource).

Comment: Then why pooling if it is a single connection?! I doubt that the object you are doing `getConnection` on is a `DataSource` if it is just translate to code to either xml (make them beans) or just use Java Config.